# MySQL 8.0.x import far slower than 5.7.x

Tags: mysql, database

i'm importing a mysqldump .sql file that was dumped from MySQL 5.7, into MySQL 8.0.12 (recently updated), and it is estimated to take 3 hours. upon reinstalling 5.7, it completed in ~15 mins. is there an issue with importing backups dumped from an old version? or is there some other issue?

Comment: Have you tested if both are configured the same? If you set smaller memory reserves for caching, indexing and whatnot it will impact the performance directly and dramatically.

Comment: @Havenard not sure how to do that... sorry, i'm a bit of a beginner. regardless, i'm using the official mysql .dmg files, so should i expect them to be configured the same?

Comment: Hard to say, but you can compare their my.cnf and see it for yourself, or just check their memory usage, if 5.7 uses significantly more memory you know it is using more cache to speed up things. Another thing I know is that MySQL 8 implemented an all new cryptographic layer to secure the communication between client and server, this implies in additional computation power to encrypt and decrypt transmitted data. If you are using a cheap VPS or something like that you may notice a CPU bottleneck because of that (though I doubt that's the case).

Comment: There is a lot you can do in the way of tuning to alter the performance of MySQL. This question is really off-topic here and a better fit on the [DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com) but be prepared to give specifics about the configuration of both systems, including general specs on hardware. If one is HDD and the other SSD that explains a lot.